# How do I solve $5^{288} \bmod 577$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I worked here down from $$125^{288} \bmod 577$$ but I don’t know how to proceed. I only know Fermat's Little Theorem and Euler’s formula and unfortunately I don’t see a way to use them. The result is $-1=576$.

Thanks for any help! :)

Edit: Solving $$5^{288} \bmod 577$$
Solved, thanks everyone:)!

Comment: Maybe starting with $125=5^3$ will help.

Comment: I already did that.

Comment: You might consider putting that in the body, then.

Comment: **Hint:** $577$ is prime and $288 \times 2=576=577-1$.

Comment: @Delta-u I know that $$5^{288}*5^{288} = 1 \bmod 577$$ from Euler’s theorem (or Fermats Little) and I thought about this option as well but still don’t know how to implement it:/

Comment: You can use the [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) but there is probably a simpler way.

Comment: I’m actually coming down from the quadratic reciprocity. I would like to show that there is no solution to $$x^2=125 \bmod 577$$. (using Legendre symbols)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually the [Legendre symbole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) and you can use the quadratic reciprocity:
$$5^{288}=5^{\frac{577-1}{2}}=\left( \frac{5}{577}\right)$$

and by the quadratic reciprocity:
$$\left( \frac{577}{5}\right) \left( \frac{5}{577}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{(577-1)(5-1)}{2 \cdot 2}}=(-1)^{576}=1$$

So it is sufficient to compute:

$$\left( \frac{577}{5}\right)= 577^\frac{5-1}{2}=577^2 \bmod 5$$
But:
$$577=2 \bmod 5$$
so:
$$577^2=2^2=4=-1 \bmod 5$$
thus:
$$\left( \frac{5}{577}\right) \cdot (-1)=1$$
i.e:
$$\left( \frac{5}{577}\right)=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

- **HINT**: $ 5^{288} \equiv x \mod 577 \Rightarrow x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 577$
  And then try to understand why one answer does not fit

Comment: Still did not work out?

Comment: The OP clearly used that to go from $125^{288}$ to $5^{288}$ already.

Comment: Um, actually, I practically proposed a solution, and the OP simply used Euler's theorem.

Comment: I honestly do not understand why you are not satisfied with my answer.

Comment: Maybe you should give some idea of the "try to understand" part, like possible methods, if you don't want to go all the way to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $25^{288} \equiv 1 \pmod{577}$, and $(-1)^2=1$.

Comment: Indeed but you also have $1^2=1$.